# How do I find the correct time zone ID for a given location?

Tags: date, datetime, time, calendar, java-time

Is there some way to determine the time zone ID of a given location?  For example, North Carolina; I search and find it uses "Eastern Time Zone" which isn't a ZoneId.  I also find that it is currently using EDT but will later use EST, which also doesn't help.  I assume I should use "America/New_York" but just finding that string was challenging enough and I still have no gaurantee (that I can find) that I'm using the correct ZoneId for North Carolina.

Some Kotlin to help find zones that might work for North Carolina:

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds

fun getAvailableZoneIdsOfHours(hours: Int) =
    getAvailableZoneIds()
        .map { ZoneId.of(it) }
        .map { it to it.rules.getStandardOffset(Instant.now()) }
        .filter { it.second == ZoneOffset.ofHours(hours) }


fun main() {
    getAvailableZoneIdsOfHours(-5).forEach { println(it.first) }
}
```

```
America/Panama -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Indiana/Petersburg -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Eirunepe -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Grand_Turk -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Fort_Wayne -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Havana -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Porto_Acre -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Louisville -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Guayaquil -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Indiana/Vevay -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Indiana/Vincennes -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Indianapolis -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Iqaluit -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Kentucky/Louisville -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Nassau -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Jamaica -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Atikokan -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Kentucky/Monticello -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Coral_Harbour -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Cayman -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Indiana/Indianapolis -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Thunder_Bay -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Indiana/Marengo -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Bogota -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Port-au-Prince -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Nipigon -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Cancun -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Lima -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Rio_Branco -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Detroit -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Pangnirtung -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Montreal -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Indiana/Winamac -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/New_York -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
America/Toronto -> ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=-05:00]
```

Given all of those, how does someone choose the correct one?

Comment: America/New_York is correct. My main sources for such questions are [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and timeanddate.com. From the latter site see for example [Tme zones in North Carolina](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/north-carolina) and [Eastern Standard Time (EST)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est). The last page lists North Carolina under *U.S. states using EST in the winter and EDT in the summer*.

Comment: @OleV.V. I found the same information but I don't see anything that tells me America/New_York is correct.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: timeanddate tells me we need EST/EDT. On the list of tz database time zones there are a number of those with country US. I want a canonical one, so geographical considerations leave us with America/New_York. All the others are limited to areas that do not include North Carolina. It’s not obvious and I don’t know how bullet-proof it is. I have settled with it as my answer.

Comment: [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) meets most requirements. You can also use [Google's timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview). Another good source is timeanddate.com e.g. if you click EST on [this page](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/north-carolina), it will take you to a page where both, New_York and North Carolina are listed.

Comment: Ah I see now, the Canonical flag eliminates some and Areas Covered eliminates Detroit and Louisville.

Comment: It’s an interesting, useful and non-trivial question. Feel free to write an answer yourself. I shall be happy to upvote.